# Powershell script to find sites having property bag in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell

We are using SharePoint 2013 and there is one property bag having key as "DATA". i want a powershell script to know in what all sites this "DATA" property is there and what is the value of this in those sites. I dont want any other property bag result.Please help

Comment: is web, site or list level property bag you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

```
  Get-SPSite -Limit all | % {
    if($_.RootWeb.Properties['DATA'] -ne $null){
      Write-Host $_.Url
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Can you please tell me that why you have used "| %" in your script? what is the purpose of that?

Comment: The first symbol is a pipe (this one -> |). It takes the output of the "Get-SPSite" command and puts it to the next command. The next command, in this script, is the percent-sign. It's an abbreviation/alias for the command "For-EachObject". So, the script gets all the Sites and iterates over them to test every site for the property bag property. Here is a list of alias: http://ilovepowershell.com/2011/11/03/list-of-top-powershell-alias/